# How to enable a column in SharePoint table to be sorted in ascending/descending order?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

Is there a way to enable a column in a list to be sorted? I've attached a screenshot of part of the table I'm working with. Only some columns are capable of being sorted. My example in the picture is the "Start Time" column. I would like to enable this feature for the "Specialty" and "Theme" columns. Both appear to be multi-line data type. If that's important. I've been searching on google for a while now and couldn't seem to find any useful information.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default behaviour, **mulitple lines of text** or **multiple value** fields are not sortable. If you have a field of type `Choice` it may be sortable if it doesn't allow for multiple values.

The above applies to both multiple lines of text as well as rich HTML content.

Comment: okay makes sense. I seem to be unable to change the data type to single line. any idea why?

Also, could i create a new column that is single line and copy the data over to that new column? I'm new to sharepoint and I cant seem to figure out how to do anything in it.

Comment: How are you changing the field? Through field declaration with XML or in the SharePoint UI? The content wouldn't match if you tried to copy from a multi line field to a single so that would not work.

Comment: I'm trying to use the sharepoint UI. That makes sense. I noticed that "specialty" was also set to rich text. When i change it to plain text some strings are still wrapped in html. for example <em>some text</em>. Then from there save changes. go back to edit the column and i'm able to change the data type to single line and sort the column. But I dont want the html tags lol

Comment: Well, you can just remove the HTML tags..?

Comment: theres over 1100 records. Is there a way to programmaticly get rid of the tags?

Comment: Yes, that should be hard. What would you want to use, C# or PowerShell for a one time conversion?

Comment: If its possible, I'm more familiar with C#

Comment: If you are satisfied with this answer, please consider marking it as the accepted answer so there are fewer questions left marked as unanswered.